# PHP Contact form - no error messages displayed

Tags: php, contact-form

I can successfully send messages to my email,
but  the error messages are not correctly displayed.

`<?php echo $result; ?>` only gives me '`array`' for the error messages.

php code here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a172c1c450730f8337bb2b33567fad1a24cc4ab

website: www.PerthBizWeb.com

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

```
$result = json_decode($url, TRUE);
```

See for yourself with:

```
<?php var_dump($result); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Json encode your result so that you can get the errors

```
$result = json_decode($visiturl, TRUE);
```